# exiftool not showing space character when using -t or -T option

Tags: exiftool

I am using the following command to save a tag with a space character:

```
exiftool -config xmp.config -overwrite_original -PropertyID=' ' /Users/admin/Downloads/Files/09913/1KingWithSofaBed_rm521_1.tif
```

Using the -X option, I can see that the space character was saved succesfully:

```
exiftool -X -filename -PropertyID /Users/admin/Downloads/Files/09913/1KingWithSofaBed_rm521_1.tif

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>

<rdf:Description rdf:about='/Users/admin/Downloads/Files/09913/1KingWithSofaBed_rm521_1.tif'
  xmlns:et='http://ns.exiftool.ca/1.0/' et:toolkit='Image::ExifTool 11.84'
  xmlns:System='http://ns.exiftool.ca/File/System/1.0/'
  xmlns:XMP-xmp='http://ns.exiftool.ca/XMP/XMP-xmp/1.0/'>
 <System:FileName>1KingWithSofaBed_rm521_1.tif</System:FileName>
 <XMP-xmp:PropertyID> </XMP-xmp:PropertyID>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

The problem is that -t or -T does not show the space:

```
exiftool -t -filename -PropertyID /Users/admin/Downloads/Files/09913/1KingWithSofaBed_rm521_1.tif

File Name   1KingWithSofaBed_rm521_1.tif
Property ID 



exiftool -T -filename -PropertyID /Users/admin/Downloads/Files/09913/1KingWithSofaBed_rm521_1.tif

1KingWithSofaBed_rm521_1.tif
```

In both cases the space is not present (I have checked the contents with an hex editor) for the PropertyID field.

Is this a limitation of exiftool or it is possible to show it usint -t or -T option?

Comment: It does appear that exiftool will trim trailing spaces when using the `-T` option.  Even in the case that there is normal text with a trailing space.  This does not happen without other output formats such as `-X` XML, `-j` JSON, and `-csv` CSV.

Comment: I've brought it up in the [Exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10873.0).  I'll post back if there's an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer from Phil Harvey](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10873.msg57914#msg57914), the author of exiftool

> You can use the (undocumented) -ec option (ExifTool 11.54 or later) to escape control characters using C-style escape sequences and preserve trailing newlines, nulls and newlines, etc

I tested it out and it seemed to preserve trailing spaces

Comment: Thanks StarGeek!